# add a field to a list of scraped tables using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I have successfully scraped the data I want (with the help of SO users), however I am missing a key to who the data in each scraped table represents.  So i am attempting to use mutate to add a field named player which is the same as the player[[j]] however this doesnt work on a list.  I have read about lapply and attempted that without success as well.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


### get a list of players
page <- (0:18)
urls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(page)) {
  url<- paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=",page[i])
  urls[[i]] <- url
}

tbl <- list()
j <- 1
for (j in seq_along(urls)) {
  tbl[[j]] <- urls[[j]] %>%   
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("a.name_link") %>%
    html_text()
  j <- j+1
  if (j == length(urls)) break
}

### join all of the names into one data frame
tbl <- ldply(tbl, data.frame)


player_tb<- as.data.frame(lapply(tbl, tolower))
colnames(player_tb) <- 'name'
player_table<- as.list(gsub(" ", "-", player_tb$name)) 
colnames(player_table) <- 'player'

#### using a list of players, get the game summary for each regular    season game, adding the player name to the table
pages<- list()
for( i in seq_along(player_table)) {
  page <- paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/",player_table[i])
  pages[[i]] <- page
}


player_stats <- list()
j <- 1
for (j in seq_along(pages)) {
  player_stats[[j]] <- pages[[j]] %>%   
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    mutate(player = player)  ## this is the piece that fails
  j <- j+1                   
  if (j == length(pages)) break
}

t <- do.call(rbind, player_stats)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `purrr` package to avoid the `for` loops and to speed things up

Using `purrr` you also have these really cool functions `safely`, `possibly` and `quietly`. Some players do not have stats and your code fails. Now it will not

The idea is to collect all the stats in a big dataframe and have an identifier column with the player's name

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# lets assume 3 pages only to do it quickly
page <- (0:2)

# no need to create a list. Just a vector
urls = paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=", page)

# define this function that collects the player's name from a url
get_the_names = function( url){
  url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("a.name_link") %>% 
    html_text()
}

# map the urls to the function that gets the names
players = map(urls, get_the_names) %>% 
  # turn into a single character vector
  unlist() %>% 
  # make lower case
  tolower() %>% 
  # replace the `space` to underscore
  str_replace_all(" ", "-")


# Now create a vector of player urls
player_urls = paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/", players )

# define a function that reads the 3rd table of the url
get_the_summary_stats <-  function(url){

  url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    html_table() %>% .[[3]] 
}

# lets read 3 players only to speed things up [otherwise it takes a significant amount of time to run...]
a_few_players = player_urls[1:3]

# get the stats 
tables = a_few_players %>% 
  # important step so I can name the rows I get in the table
  set_names() %>% 
  #map the player urls to the function that reads the 3rd table
  # note the `safely` wrap around the get_the_summary_stats' function
  # since there are players with no stats and causes an error (eg.brenden-aaronson )
  # the output will be a list of lists [result and error]
  map(., safely(get_the_summary_stats)) %>% 
  # collect only the `result` output (the table) INTO A DATA FRAME
  # There is also an `error` output
  # also, name each row with the players name
  map_df("result", .id = "player") %>% 
  #keep only the player name (remove the www.mls.... part)
  mutate(player = str_replace(player, "https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/", "")) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Lets see how many we got

```
  tables %>% count(player)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  player                n
  <chr>             <int>
1 anatole-abang        81
2 saad-abdul-salaam   136
```

Now you can filter the dataframe by the player's name

```
  tables %>% 
  filter(player == "anatole-abang")

# A tibble: 81 x 14
   player        Date       Match      Result Appearance  MINS     G     A  SHTS   SOG    FC    FS     Y     R
   <chr>         <chr>      <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 anatole-abang 10/28/2018 ORL @ RBNY W 0-1  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2 anatole-abang 10/21/2018 RBNY @ PHI W 1-0  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3 anatole-abang 10/06/2018 RBNY @ SJ  W 3-1  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4 anatole-abang 9/30/2018  ATL @ RBNY W 0-2  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5 anatole-abang 9/22/2018  TOR @ RBNY W 0-2  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6 anatole-abang 9/16/2018  RBNY @ DC  T 3-3  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 7 anatole-abang 9/01/2018  RBNY @ MTL L 0-3  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8 anatole-abang 8/29/2018  HOU @ RBNY W 0-1  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 9 anatole-abang 8/26/2018  DC @ RBNY  W 0-1  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
10 anatole-abang 8/22/2018  RBNY @ NYC T 1-1  Unused Sub     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 71 more rows
```

Comment: this works perfectly.  Thanks for your time.  I have not used the purr package before.  Is there a sys.sleep() I can implement with the purr package that would make for more responsible scraping?

Comment: Yes there is! See here for some nice tricks  https://www.hvitfeldt.me/2018/01/purrr-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: I tried this `tables = a_few_players %>% 

set_names() %>% 
map(., ~{ Sys.sleep(5)
  safely(get_the_summary_stats)
  }) %>% 
map_df("result", .id = "player") %>% 
#keep only the player name (remove the www.mls.... part)
mutate(player = str_replace(player, "https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/", "")) %>% 
as_tibble()`   but I get an error `Dont know how to pluck`   Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is due to the fact the player status is returning 4 separate tables and not one.
I have simplified your code slightly, but is not a final solution is the end result here is a list of lists.  You can now use `lapply` on the final list to collect each individual table and combine them if desired.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

### get a list of players
page <- (0:18)
urls<- paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=",page)

tbl <- list()
for (j in seq_along(urls)) {
  tbl[[j]] <- urls[j] %>%   
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("a.name_link") %>%
    html_text()
#add a delay so not to overwhelm server
 Sys.sleep(0.75)
}

### join all of the names into one data frame
player_tb<- tolower(unlist(tbl))
player_table <-data.frame(player= gsub(" ", "-", player_tb))

#### using a list of players, get the game summary for each regular    season game, adding the player name to the table
pages <- paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/",player_table$player)

player_stats <- list()
for (j in seq_along(pages)) {
  player_stats[[j]] <- pages[j] %>%   
    read_html() %>%   
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table() 
  #determine if the status are present
  #bind player name to the table 
  if (length(ttables)==4){
    player_stats[[j]]<-cbind(player_table$player[j], ttables[[3]])
  } else {
    player_stats[[j]]<-cbind(player_table$player[j], ttables[[1]])
  }
  #add a delay so not to overwhelm server
  #get up and stretch your legs!
  Sys.sleep(0.75)  
}
#combine all of the player status into one dataframe
finalanswer<-do.call(rbind, player_stats)
```

This code assumes the play stats has 1 or 4 tables associated with it, if this is not true then the if/else statement needs to change to match.
Hope this helps you along the way.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e...very helpful.  I see the issue with the 4 tables. I only want the 3rd table.  I tried  `player_stats <- list()
for (j in seq_along(pages)) {
  player_stats[[j]] <- pages[j] %>%   
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node("table") %>%
    .[3] %>%
    html_table() 
}`  but this doesnt work.  Any suggestions on getting just the specific table?

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e - i appreciate your time.  I tried the following modification including trycatch - the program runs without error but collects no data.  `player_stats <- list()
for (j in seq_along(pages)) {
  tryCatch(
  player_stats[[j]] <- pages[j] %>%   
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node("table") %>%
    .[3] %>%
    html_table(),
  error = function(e){0}
  )
}`